# What non malicious uses are there for ping's flood (-f) option?

Tags: networking, security, ping

I have been reading up on common ways in which people attack each other on the internet through things like DDOS attacks etc, and how one would defend oneself from such attacks, and I have come across the fact that with the Ubuntu `ping` tool there is a "[Flood ping](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/ping.8.html)" option:

```
ping -f <WhatToPing>
```

So I would assume that there must be other uses for ping flooding then, other than the malicious DOS attack one, so that is really my question, in what circumstances would you normally use the `-f` option when not attempting to do something malicious?

Comment: Not to say this is off topic here, but it does seem like it would be very much at home on [SF] or perhaps even [security.SE].

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That's obviously **;-)** to test whether your system hardening has worked out and that your TCP/IP stack will not be flooded by ping flooding *any more* …

E.g. that your system won't keel over by ***dropping*** the enormous amount of ICMP packets that it receives.

Comment: @Reid: I'm very sorry, but the answer is to someone I know on this site so telling him that it's obvious is no problem...  ;-)  So I rolled back your edit.

Comment: But no one else knows that. I don't think ad hominems are appropriate in public, regardless of whether you know the person or not. It sets a bad standard of behavior.

Comment: Let's agree to disagree that this one is an ad hominem, but to humour you, I'll add a bold smiley to the statement....  Feel free to join the Ask Ubuntu General chat room and look at the banter between @Toroidal and me...  ;-)

Comment: As someone said on [vi.se], "obviousness isn't universal."

Comment: @muru I think that's the point of the joke. That said, including the smiley face is an improvement.

Comment: "Obviously" may or may not have been abrasive, but it certainly wasn't "ad hominem".  "Ad hominem" means a personal attack (literally "to the man").

I think the smiley face makes the joke more *obvious*, but it probably isn't necessary given the sassiness of the rest of the answer **;-)**

Comment: @KyleStrand Perhaps I need to start including smileys too. :D

Answer (score 16):

This can be used to check if the network is reliable or if it is overloaded. The usual one ICMP message per seconds would be too slow for such purposes. Please note that 100 ICMP packets per seconds is very far from being a DOS attack in today's networks. That is only about 150 KB/s even if you specifically send unusually large ping messages.

Comment: I definitely second this.  Many years ago I went to considerable effort to heavily load a network in order to prove that a certain switch would misbehave.  I had to do it entirely with standard tools as their techs had already blamed my program for the problem.  Only when I could make that portion of the network fall over from the command line would they consider there was a real issue.

Comment: It's by far the worst tool available for this purpose though

Comment: @Aki it's also something like 30 years old :)

Answer (score 16):

In addition to the other answers listed here about confirming how well hardened a host is, I have used the ping -f as a poor man's bandwidth testing tool for very narrow links.

More comprehensive tools like Fluke and Iperf require a cooperating agent at both ends of your link, but if you wish to test bandwidth to a point on your network that cannot easily have a cooperating endpoint (such as a client's demarc router) then as long as the endpoint can at least reply to large ICMP echo packets then you can determine a lower bound to available bandwidth at that time.

Comment: I often use a flood ping in testing networks.  I've been working on MANETs for quite a while now and it's a very quick way to test a link and it's 'lossy-ness'.

Answer (score 10):

Long ago, I was in a university computer lab where we had... interesting wiring.  Apparently, the signal in [thicknet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10BASE5) is the same as the signal in [thinnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10BASE2) and some engineering student had created what looked like a terminator for thicknet and thinnet smashed together... a barrel connector with 10b5 on one side and 10b2 on the other.  This was obviously not anything resembling a best practice in any sense of the word.

This worked, for some definition of worked.  Thicknet was a bit pickier about the standing wave in the wire than thinnet was, but we had a thicknet cable that went along one wall, this connector, and then thinnet on the other wall.

The problem occurred when we added machines to the thinnet side because we wouldn't get the standing wave right and machines would disappear from the network until we got the right combination of lengths of wire between the thinnet T plugs.

There was one machine (lets say it was at 10.10.10.10) that was plugged into a different part of the network (the 10bT part) so was completely unaffected by all of the other network changes.  When we would add (or remove) machines from the network, we would set up:

```
ping -f 10.10.10.10 > /dev/audio
```

As long as packets are flowing to the machine, the speaker was making noise.  Network not visible for that machine and its silent.

And then go about trying different cables.  When all of the machines were chattering away, we were done.

Comment: That's redneck ingenuity right there I don't care who you are!

Answer (score 8):

You can watch the dots from across the room while wiggling the cables to find the faulty connection.

Comment: FYI, your answer appeared here: http://roflcopter.pl/7780 It's a Polish site with funny quotes for geeks/nerds.  I'm not affiliated with the site in any way, just a subscriber ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use it for stress testing your own machine as others have said, however at the place I'm interning at the IT professional usually uses it when rebooting a machine remotely, when the machine is back online he will know because it will start responding to the requests.

Answer (score 1):

I've used ping -f in the past to see if my lines are dropping packets at higher rates and to see if router error counters are increasing. According to the man page only a 0 rate ( which is as fast as it can go ) can be executed by a super-user.

I agree with others that ping -f is not a great tool to use for this purpose. Netperf, iperf or other bandwidth tools are much better.